# Regex to Remove Content Inside Specific Brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have brackets that contain data as so:

`[vc_tag][/vc_tag]`

Where tag could be any of about 30 pieces of text.

I need some regex that will remove any brackets that contain `vc_`

I have this, but it removes all instead of just `vc_`:

`$data = preg_replace('/\\[(?>[^\\]]*)\\]/', '', $content);`

I also tried:

`$data = preg_replace('/\\[(vc_[^\\]]*)\\]/', '', $content);`

which removes the opening `[vc_tag]` but not the closing `[/vc_tag]`

This is written in PHP by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$data = preg_replace('~\[/?vc_[^]]*]~', '', $content);
```